# How to add user info along with address info in a single form using 2 content types?

Tags: 7, users

I have a content type '**Person**', one field of which has a entity reference to a content type '**Address**'.

I would like an anonymous user to add their information along with their address in a single form using these two content types. What should I use to do that?  Do I have to code it or does a module or a combination of modules help me?

Also similarly, for a logged-in user, I would like them to be able to edit their information which was previously saved. How do I do that?

**Notes**:

- I would like the anonymous users to register and also provide a few more pieces of profile information. Of course, I do limit what else they can do till they get approved by the administrator.
- I could capture the address information in the same content type but the reason I am thinking of separate content type is because two people can have the same address and I don't want to have redundant information. It would also provide me a way to figure out people who live in the same household. Also, I don't want to lose the address if someone moves and decides to update their address. It looks like I can add/edit two different nodes in the same page. If not reference, how? Do I have to code for it or there are modules that can do it?
- My choice of 'address' as an example was a bad one. My broader question is: Given two tables with one of the fields as a foreign key into the other, in Drupal, how can I create, update, delete corresponding rows in the two tables at the same time. The interface being user friendly UI for end user. Does I have to do this in code, or is there a single module or a set of modules that can be used to accomplish this? I am not looking for a full solution as much as pointers in the right direction.

Comment: Your question was somehow unclear , are you going to allow anonymous users to add some data to an specific content type?

Comment: although you can add/edit two different nodes on one page, I don't know that you can do it with a reference, since the referenced node needs to exist before hand in order for the reference field to work. Why not include address information in the same content type?

Comment: In order to get around that duplicate information, you would have to expose the address content type, so that a new user would 'select' an address from an existing list if possible - that is a HUGE privacy issue, and  would constitute a breach of privacy (illegal) in many countries - even if it's auto-complete, to find out if someone had created an account you just start typing their address. It's a bad idea. duplicate addresses should be irrelevant (my opinion), given the miniscule space they would require

Comment: @AjayR : I integrated various of your comments (to your own question) IN your question (within "Notes"), which should help others to digest your question and your related comments. Please review what I added within those 'notes', and correct/rework where appropriate, ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me that you should have a look at the [Entity connect](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityconnect) module. Here are some details about it (from its project page):

> Entity Connect now expands both
>
> - [Entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference)
> - [References](https://www.drupal.org/project/references) (node_reference and user_reference)
>
> fields by adding "add new content" and "edit current content" buttons.
>
> It will work with all default widgets provided by [Entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) and [References](https://www.drupal.org/project/references).
>
> The Drupal module will allow you to dynamically create and edit entities (see bellow for the list of currently working entity types)
>   which should be referenced into an Entity reference field.
>
> It will help you to improve the User Experience for creation of new entities or edition of linked entities on your entity reference fields.
>
> The "add a new" button will enable you to add / create a new entity. The first form will be cached then the new form will be generated. Once the new form is completed and saved the user will return to the original form.
>
> The "edit" button will take the user to the edit form of the referenced entity. Once the user is done editing, he is sent back to the previous form.

Refer to [Creating related records on the master](http://jay-epstein.com/relativity/creating-related-records-master) for a first impression/intro about this module. This article is part of the illuminating [Relativity Model for Drupal](http://jay-epstein.com/relativity/overview), for which this is an introduction to it (quoted from this linked page):

> The Relativity Data Model for Drupal is a zero-custom-code, collection of steps, procedures and methods that strive to help site builders, users and site visitors interact with Drupal in a far easier and more efficient way. This is done by:
>
> - Data architecture and data modeling merging as a single step through a documentation procedure.
> - Customized user interfaces that cater to individual workflows throughout permission roles.
> - Multi-level relational data structures that relate to other multi-level relational structures.
> - Mimicking the concept of database joins within Drupal's UI's.
> - Vastly reducing the size of Drupal sites by a small handful of modules that provide greater power, speed and expansion capabilities.

The *small handfull of modules* (cfr. the last bullet) is detailed on [Interface elegance and experience](http://jay-epstein.com/relativity/interface-elegance-and-experience) and is like so (apart from Drupal core):

- https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools
- https://www.drupal.org/project/date
- https://www.drupal.org/project/entity
- https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference
- https://www.drupal.org/project/entityconnect
- https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group
- https://www.drupal.org/project/token
- https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto
- https://www.drupal.org/project/views

Answer (score 0):

You probably should have a look to [Profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) module. If you really want to use content types, you should have a look to [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) and then configure permissions to be sure users can only edit their own content.

Hope that helps ;-)

Comment: Thanks, vbouchet.  I am using profile2 already. but like @Geoff mentioned above, I am running into 'referenced node need to exist already' issue.